# Jquery/JS Show dynamic checkbox input group title if at least one or more are checked and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to show input group title if at least one checkbox is checked, and hide title if no checkboxes checked. Each group has his own title and data-value. There may be 5+ input groups.

```
Here is the codepen: [Example code here][1]


[1]: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyrQgW
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
});
```

```css
.output {
  margin-top:45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block" data-value="1">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="1">group1</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item4
</div>

<div class="group-block" data-value="2">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="2">group2</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item4
</div>

<div class="output">HERE SHOW TITLES</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`enter code here`

At the end, I'm not so good with JS/Jquery but I was trying to make it work for a few hours and have a feeling that I go very deep but there is a 2 line solution.

Thanks for help

Comment: and what did you tried in JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  check()
})

function check() {
  $(".group-block").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".group-title").css("display", $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length ? "block" : "none")
  })
}
```

It will check if any checkbox has been checked on both `.ready()` and `.change()` statement, and show or hide the title depends on the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  check()
})

function check() {
  $(".group-block").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".group-title").css("display", $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length ? "block" : "none")
  })
}
```

```css
.output {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block" data-value="1">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="1">group1</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item4
</div>

<div class="group-block" data-value="2">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="2">group2</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item4
</div>

<div class="output">HERE SHOW TITLES</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Demo 2 from coment**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  check()
})

function check() {
  $(".output").text("");
  $(".group-title").hide();

  $(".group-block").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length)
      $(".output").text($(".output").text() + $(this).find(".group-title").text())
  })
}
```

```css
.output {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-block" data-value="1">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="1">group1</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item4
</div>

<div class="group-block" data-value="2">
  <h1 class="group-title" data-value="2">group2</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item4
</div>

<div class="output">HERE SHOW TITLES</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works just perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: One more question:
Can we somehow make the titles visible all the time, but if checked clone the title and append to <div class="output">HERE SHOW TITLES</div> and if no checkbox checked remove that title? Thanks

Comment: Not sure i understand your question, where do you want `<div class="output">HERE SHOW TITLES</div>`

Comment: I mean if any checkbox in group is checked copy the title of that group and add somewhere in document.If you take a look in html you will see in the bottom a div with output classname Right now it's hiding and showing titles exactly

Comment: @Gabriel747 check snippet 2

Comment: Awesome, now I got exactly what needed. Thanks again, you saved so much time for me :D

Comment: Sorry if I'm annoying, but is it also possible on click added title change all related checkboxes unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.group-block h1').hide();
  $('.output').click(function(){
    $('.group-block h1').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('.group-block').find('h1').show();
  });
});
```

Suggestion: You may want to hide the titles initially with CSS.